# Cannot connect: invalid settings OSX

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Im getting this error but i can not find phpmyadmin folder to change config.inc.php. Any suggestion?

> > Error MySQL said: Documentation
>
> Cannot connect: invalid settings.  Connection for controluser as
>   defined in your configuration failed.  phpMyAdmin tried to connect to
>   the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should
>   check the host, username and password in your configuration and make
>   sure that they correspond to the information given by the
>   administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: try: **# find / -name config.inc.php**. will search for these file in any directory

Comment: i found it in /Applications/XAMP/xampfiles/bin/ but its empty

Comment: Can you still connect to mysql (not through PhpMyAdmin) ?

Comment: show if there are a default config and copy this # ls  /Applications/XAMP/xampfiles/bin/*config*

Comment: @Sylvain i cannot connect to mysql im getting error that is error with database

Comment: @BerndBuffen i dont get anything with that command

Comment: take a look in /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmyadmin/config for the config.inc.php

Comment: i dont have phpmyadmin folder there

Comment: If you can't connect to your database at all then the problem is on MySQL side and not PhpMyAdmin.